# Where can we get this data regarding ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

We want to get the information regarding The average amount of data in bytes passing through the ELB per request/response pair, in the case of a layer-7 ELB, or the rate, in bytes per second, of traffic that will traverse a TCP connection (on average) in the case of a layer-4 ELB.

could some one help?

I am expecting average amount of data in bytes passing through the ELB per request/response pair.

Comment: Check ALB metrics

Answer (score -1):

Enable ELB access log, by default ELB access log is disable, you need to enable this then it will store log data in S3 Backet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).